# How can I define a completely different name to appear in the text when I use \citet

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I'm writing an article and I want to cite a standard. I want the name that appears in the text before the number to be different from the name that appears in the bibliography.

I use `elsarticle-num-names` as bibliography style.

For example I want to define something like ANOTHER_NAME

```
@article{astmc33,
  title={Standard specification for concrete aggregates},
  author={{ASTM C33}},
  journal={ASTM International, West Conshohocken~(PA)},
  year={2018},
  ***ANOTHER_NAME*** = {AAAAAAAA}
}

\citet{astmc33}
```

and the output be like:

> AAAAAAAA~[1]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're employing the `natbib` citation management package, you may achieve your typesetting objective by (a) using the package's citation aliasing feature and (b) defining a custom command called, say, `\altcitet`, which outputs the alias and the entry's associated number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{astmc33,
  title={Standard specification for concrete aggregates},
  author={{ASTM C33}},
  journal={ASTM International, West Conshohocken~(PA)},
  year={2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\defcitealias{astmc33}{AAAAAAAA}

% define a macro to combine the outputs of \citetalias and \citenum:
\newcommand{\altcitet}[1]{\citetalias{#1} [\citenum{#1}]}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\noindent
\altcitet{astmc33} vs.\ \citet{astmc33}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```